# mysql installation in mysql in Linux

Tags: linux

I am installing  mysql-5.1.49-linux-i686-glibc23.tar.gz in Linux/Debian machine.I am following the steps from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/installing-binary.html

Problem is that the 1. when I run the command(for verifying package integrity) $md5sum mysql-5.1.49-linux-i686-glibc23.tar.gz The output does not  matches the one displayed on the download page immediately below the respective package.

I ignored this one and untar the package. It's that there should be data sirectory in the installation directory but that is not available.So How can i proceed further?

Comment: I guess there's a reason why `apt-get install mysql-server` wasn't sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

If the md5 sums dont match the download is most likely defective or corrupted in some way.

I recommend to download the archive again and verify the checksum is correct.

Comment: From where I can get mysql other than http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/ 
Thanks